# Take dashes out of MYSQL date

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my situation.
I am sending records to database through php file. Then I have a date field being set with now(). It adds the date in this format: 2013-08-01

Then I am exporting the database to a csv. It all works fine. However, I need to take the dashes out when I am exporting it to the csv. So I need it to read: 20130801

Is there a way to do this? Here is my export to csv code:

```
$from = $_REQUEST['from'];
$to = $_REQUEST['to'];
$filename = "APGE_ELEC_" . $to;
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'".csv"');

    $hostname = ""; //SET SERVER/HOSTNAME
    $dbusername = ""; //SET DATABASE USERNAME
    $dbname = ""; //SET DATABASE NAME
    $dbpassword = ""; //SET DATABASE USERNAME

$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $dbusername, $dbpassword) 
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

$selected = mysql_select_db($dbname,$dbhandle) 
  or die("Could not select Data Base");

//$query = "SELECT * FROM v88374 WHERE ((date >= '$from') AND (date <= '$to'))";
$query = "SELECT * FROM v88374 WHERE date >= DATE_FORMAT('" . $from . "', '%Y%m%d') AND date <=  DATE_FORMAT('" . $to . "', '%Y%m%d')"; 
//$query = "SELECT * FROM v88374 WHERE date >= DATE_FORMAT($from) AND date <=  DATE_FORMAT($to)";

$export = mysql_query ($query ) or die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error( ) );

$fields = mysql_num_fields ( $export );

for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++ )
{
    $header .= mysql_field_name( $export , $i ) ."|" . "\t";
}

while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $export ) )
{
    $line = '';
    foreach( $row as $value )
    {                                            
        if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) )
        {
            $value = "\t";
        }
        else
        {
            $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
            $value = $value . '|' . "\t";
        }
        $line .= $value;
    }
    $data .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
}
$data = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $data );

if ( $data == "" )
{
    $data = "\n(0) Records Found!\n"; 

}

print "$header\n$data";


exit();
```

The $to and $from are parameters for searching for date range in the database. So we can leave that alone.

Comment: Where are you stuck in specific?

Comment: I suggest don't format your date in MySQL query. Fetch it as it is from the database then at the time of display format it accordingly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to select the formatted time

```
$query = "SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date,"%Y%m%d") FROM v88374 WHERE date >= DATE_FORMAT('" . $from . "', '%Y%m%d') AND date <=  DATE_FORMAT('" . $to . "', '%Y%m%d')";
```

Comment: This worked perfect. The only thing is, it added an extra field name with %Y%m%d in it. Is there a way to stay as 'date' as the field name?

Comment: Yes, use SELECT ... DATE_FORMAT(date,"%Y%m%d") AS formateddate ... I wouldn't use date as it is bad practice to overwrite existing field names.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datefield, '%Y%m%d')
```

if you want to do it directly in the database.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be easily tackled by taking advantage of the way MySQL processes the value in the Date field. Just add 0 and the dashes will be removed

```html
select now();
//gives 2019-12-03 08:44:10

select now()+0;
//gives 20191203084504
```

You can process this integer as a string and get whatever parts of this are needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str_replace()` like you did for the quotes, but modify it for dashes, replacing them with empty strings.

```
$value = str_replace( '-' , '' , $value );
```

This poses some danger, though. What if you have other data types that use dashes? They'd be corrupted. Another option is to use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [`checkdate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) to make sure it's a `date` before you remove the dashes. Example:

```
$dt = explode("-", $value); // Yields array([0] => 2013,  [1] => 08, [2] => 01)
// checkdate(int month, int day, int year)
if (checkdate($dt[1], $dt[2], $dt[0])) {
    // It's a date.
    $value = str_replace('-','',$value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$newDate = str_replace('-', '', $oldDate)
```

Is that what you're looking for?

In addition php provides some awesome date formatting features: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$date="2013-08-01";

$converted_date=date("Ymd", strtotime($date));
```

Comment: painfully slow if all you want to do is strip out the slashes. a simple `str_replace()` would be FAR faster than a round-trip through the date parseing system.

Comment: @MarcB: I accept, but this approach may help him/her in the future when needed to convert the format :)

Answer (score 0):

I tend to prefer a more OOP approach. This way if you ever need to change the format, you can easily modify it.

```
$date = new DateTime($date_from_mysql);    
echo $date->format('Ymd'); // Or adjust the format how you like
```

Of course, you shouldn't be using the deprecated `ext/mysql` extension for new projects anyway.